# uitableview autolayout custom cell causing extra height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

uitableview autolayout custom cell causing extra height. Unable to detect where causing the issue while in different project working fine. [image]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [_stubCell layoutSubviews];

    [self configureCell:_stubCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat height = [_stubCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return height;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 40.f;
}

- (void)configureCell:(CCACustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.customLabel.text = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.customLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:16.0];
    cell.customLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x32383B);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CCACustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please check the text string for the UILabel assigned if it contain any "\n" next line character in the starting.

Comment: no friend , there is no "\n" next line character

Comment: @santanu, is these are dynamic cells or static cells???

Comment: dynamic cell ...

Comment: @santanu, whats the screensize you are checking???

Comment: iPhone 6s .....

Comment: actually i checked the Github Project of `CCACustomCell`. Its working perfectly without any issues with your same code

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide details on how are you creating _stubCell?It might be due to some constraint on label.
Have you tried with calculating string height?

```
+(CGFloat )calculateStringHeight:(NSString *)string WithFont:(UIFont *)font andSidePadding:(CGFloat )padding{

  CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width - (2*padding), 1000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
  return rect.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return required height for your Label like this. Where you should pass Your description label width in LABEL_DESCRIPTION_WIDTH.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(LABEL_DESCRIPTION_WIDTH , 9999);
   NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE], NSFontAttributeName,nil];
   NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributes:attributesDictionary];
   CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
   return requiredHeight;
}
```